# Transition probabilities of a binned time series

Tags: python, time-series, markov-chains

My data:

```
data
Out[84]: 
array([ 1.79,  1.93,  1.81,  1.79,  3.87,  5.75,  7.25,  5.03, 11.11,
       11.53, 13.79,  4.41,  4.68,  7.9 ,  3.49,  1.8 ,  1.85,  2.02,
        1.81,  2.33,  2.13,  1.92,  1.74,  1.84])
```

I defined three ranges/bins in which each element can be:

```
b = 3
binsize = (Max-Min)/b
d = {}

for i in range(0,b):
    upperlimit = Min + (i+1)*binsize
    d["Bin "+str(i)+" upper limit"] = upperlimit

d
Out[83]: 
{'Bin 0 upper limit': 5.756666666666667,
 'Bin 1 upper limit': 9.773333333333333,
 'Bin 2 upper limit': 13.790000000000001}
```

So
Bin 0 goes from Min to 5.756
Bin 1 from 5.756 to 9.7733
Bin 2 from 9.7733 to 13.79

I would like to calculate the probability, given an element X, that X+1 will be in a certain bin. The transition probability from one bin to another so to say.
How would I do that? I am struggling a bit to wrap my head around that.

So basically, at any point in time t (first element of the array is in t=0, last in t=23)
I want to know what the transition probability of going from one bin to another is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has some methods that are useful here, including binning so you do not need to do it by hand. Hope you do not mind using pandas -- anyway it should give you an idea on how to do it if you want to do it "by hand"

let's start by putting your data into bins. Here `pd.cut` will split your data into 3 bins and return a bin for each point. we also put the original data into  a dataframe as column `'x'`

```
import pandas as pd

b = 3
bins = pd.cut(data, b, labels = False)
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':data})
```

Now let's put `bins` into `df` as 'from' column, indicating which bin each `x` point is in, and let's `shift` it to show where it is going to be at the next step

```
df['from'] = bins
df['to'] = df['from'].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna().astype(int)
df
```

Now your df looks like this:

```
      x    from    to
--  ---  ------  ----
 0    1       0     0
 1    1       0     0
 2    1       0     0
 3    1       0     0
 4    3       0     0
 5    5       0     1
 6    7       1     0
 7    5       0     2
 8   11       2     2
 9   11       2     2
10   13       2     0
11    4       0     0
12    4       0     1
13    7       1     0
14    3       0     0
15    1       0     0
16    1       0     0
17    2       0     0
18    1       0     0
19    2       0     0
20    2       0     0
21    1       0     0
22    1       0     0
```

now we can `groupby` the `df` on 'from' and 'to' and calculate how many times your process transitioned from a given `from` bin to a given `to` bin:

```
df.groupby(['from','to']).count().reset_index().rename(columns = {'x':'count'})
```

this looks like this:

```
   from to  count
0   0   0   15
1   0   1   2
2   0   2   1
3   1   0   2
4   2   0   1
5   2   2   2
```

eg your process transitioned from bin0 to bin1 2 times, etc

you can get this in a matrix form as well:

```
df.groupby(['from','to']).count().unstack(level = 1).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

it will look like this:

```
x
to  0   1   2
from            
0   15  2   1
1   2   0   0
2   1   0   2
```

Comment: wow! This is precisely what I needed. I was doing long work-arounds that were not really flexible when b would change. Thank you so much!